# Login issue with django cached sessions

Tags: python, django, session, caching

I'm having an issue with using using the cache backend for django

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
```

When I set the session engine to use cache instead of the DB. I am unable to login. From the app logs I can see that the auth is successful, the response also contains the set-cookie header for session_id. So that all seems to be working. Except that I am just returned to the login page after logging in. I guess this session

If I comment out the session engine, it reverts back to using the DB session engine and works as expected.

This is working on my python 2.7 machine locally, on the server where this doesn't work there is python 2.6 running (I'm not sure if this is relevant, but it's about the only real difference I can find). The pip packages are mostly identical, I think this all come from within django anyway.
I'm using django 1.6.7 in both places.

Comment: How is your caching configured? E.g. the CACHES setting? Most likely the caching isn't setup properly/sanely for use as a session engine.

Comment: Its on the django default - which is the in memory cache. I'll have dig around that it's worth me double checking

Answer (score 3):

LocMemCache isn't suitable for production.

> You should only use cache-based sessions if you’re using the Memcached cache backend. The local-memory cache backend doesn’t retain data long enough to be a good choice, and it’ll be faster to use file or database sessions directly instead of sending everything through the file or database cache backends. Additionally, the local-memory cache backend is NOT multi-process safe, therefore probably not a good choice for production environments.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/#using-cached-sessions

Generally when I'm deploying for the first time I'll start with the DB Cache configured just to prove the configuration. Then switch it over Memcache or Redis.

Comment: Didn't realise it was not multi process safe. I'll look into a switch to memcached

Comment: When I first went through this I found the docs kind of hard to read and interpret. Glad you've got it straight now :-)